# Set SQL WHERE value using an element from a list

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a variable with a list on it and I need to use its value for my find option. I get an error when I set my id_user to id_u.

Here is the list

```
id_u = user_key[0]
```

This is my SELECT and WHERE

```
find = ("SELECT * FROM hashtags WHERE id_user=id_u")
```

Comment: I strongly discourage you from building SQL via text concatenation where using parameters was possible. What might happen if the value of `user_key[0]` was : `"0; DROP TABLE hashtags; --"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate SELECT string with variable value.
Try like this:

```
id_u = user_key[0]
find = ("SELECT * FROM hashtags WHERE id_user=" + id_u)
```